# The new answer sorting menu appears in English even on language specific sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sorting, localization

It appears that the new sorting menu has been rolled out network-wide, but no exception was made for our language specific sites:

- Stack Overflow на русском ([Question from screen capture](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290))  [image: Dropdown menu with English values on Stack Overflow на русском]
- Stack Overflow en español ([Question from screen capture](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977))  [image: Dropdown menu with English values on Stack Overflow en español]
- Stack Overflow em Português ([Question from screen capture](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193))  [image: Dropdown menu with English values on Stack Overflow em Português]
- スタック・オーバーフロー ([Question from screen capture](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/19481)) [image: Dropdown menu with English values on スタック・オーバーフロー]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has now been fixed on all the international SO sites:

- Stack Overflow на русском

  > [image: Dropdown menu with Russian values on Stack Overflow на русском]
- Stack Overflow en español

  > [image: Dropdown menu with Spanish values on Stack Overflow en español]
- スタック・オーバーフロー

  > [image: Dropdown menu with Japanese values on スタック・オーバーフロー]
- Stack Overflow em Português:

  > [image: Dropdown menu with Portuguese values on Stack Overflow em Português]

Comment: Just fixed it for SOpt, so this should be fixed everywhere now. Lemme know if you see any more weirdness ;)

Comment: @Jnat: Thanks for the update! There *is* more weirdness I'd like to report :) The "Highly active question" notice on [pt.SO posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE9qS.png) have not been translated. See, for e.g.,  this post on [Spanish.SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94ZYW.png), where the notice *has* been translated.

Comment: Since that's a completely separate part of the UI, mind putting it in a separate post, for tracking purposes?

Comment: @Jnat: I was going to, but I was confused whether to post it on MSE or on pt.SO, since it only occurs there and nowhere else..

Comment: SOpt seems to make more sense, if it's been translated elsewhere.

Comment: @JNat: Reported on [pt.SO](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8748/highly-active-question-notices-on-this-portuguese-so-have-not-been-translated).

Comment: Cool, thanks! Lessee if the community translates this themselves, or if the mods escalate to the CM team ;)